# Puppteer: waitForResponse возвращает объект запроса при false в callback обработчике

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Имеется авторизация на сайте, перед нажатием кнопки создаю `promise` с `waitForResponse` на ожидание запроса с ошибкой (если она будет) и ожидаю его решения или решения `promise` с `waitFornavigation`:

```js
let waitPasswordError = page.waitForResponse(async (response) => {
    console.log(response.request().url())
    if(response.request().url().includes('login.do') && response.status() === 200) {
        const {content: {data}} = await response.json();

        if(data){
            let result = data.titleMsg !== undefined;
            console.log('Error:', result);
            return result;
        }

    } else return false;
});
let waitLoginRedirect = page.waitForNavigation( {timeout: 0, 'waitUntil' : 'networkidle0' } );
await page.click('#signin');
await Promise.any([waitLoginRedirect, waitPasswordError])...
```

`Promise waitPasswordError` должен решится при условии что url  содержит `login.do`, запрос получил статус `200`, а объект ответа полученного с `response.json()`, в свойстве `data` содержит поле `titleMsg`. и не смотря на то, что `console.log('Error:', result);` пишет в консоль `Error: false`, `Promise` возвращает объект запроса на `login.do`,при этом если вывести его в консоль то видно что он естественно не содержит требуемого поля:

```js
{
  content: {
    data: {
      loginResult: 'success',
      loginSucResultAction: 'loginResult',
      loginType: 'pwd',
      loginScene: 'normal',
      resultCode: 100,
    },
    status: 0,
    success: true
  },
  hasError: false
}
```

Comment: А как вы проверяете результат `await Promise.any([waitLoginRedirect, waitPasswordError])`, чтобы убедиться, что там объект запроса на `login.do`?

Comment: тем же `Promise.any(...).then(console.log)` это прекрасно видно, возвращается объект `HTTPResponse`, так же я вешал отдельный then - `waitPasswordError.then(console.log)` (так что с 100% уверенностью видно что он переходит в состояние resolved и возвращает объект), хотя этого не должно происходить тк ни один запрос не содержит titleMsg и это подтверждается выводом в консоль в callback. Показывает `Error: false` и последующий console.log с `HTTPResponse`

Comment: Не может быть так, что у вас устаревшая версия puppteer? Поддержка колбеков этого метода, возвращающих промисы, была добавлена недавно, до этого промисы воспринимались как truthy-значения. См. https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4323 и https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/6624 — т.е. нужна версия https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v6.0.0

Comment: Действительно, сейчас думая над подобным, мне пришло в голову что возможно оно так и есть, тк запрос там только 1 и если промис подразумевается как true, то оно сразу от отдаст объект запроса как только я отдам промис. А `puppteer` у меня действительно старой версии - `4.0.1` Мне и в голову не приходило что такое поведение возможно так как это никогда не происходило при использовании `puppeteer`. Старую версию я использовал из-за проблем с переназначением webdriver в последней.  Прошу добавить ответ, чтобы я мог пометить его как верный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mожет быть так, что у вас устаревшая версия puppteer. Поддержка колбеков этого метода, возвращающих промисы, была добавлена недавно, до этого промисы воспринимались как truthy-значения.

См. [issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/4323) и [PR](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/6624) — т.е. нужна как минимум версия [6.0.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v6.0.0).